# How do I make commands like cat and less keep tab characters?

Tags: cat

Is there a way to make `cat`, `less` etc. print tab characters instead of tabs being converted to spaces? I am annoyed by this when I copy code from the terminal to an editor.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing two problems here.

1. First, destination editor can covert TAB to number of spaces. Some
   editor has default feature to convert TAB to number of spaces.  If
   you disable this feature TAB character you copied from terminal will
   be copied as TAB(instead of space) to an editor.
   Windows Notepad++ has similar feature 
   [image: Notepad ++ feature to remove tab as spaces]. If you are using vim, this page will be helpful for
   [vim tab and space conversion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces)
2. Another, source file  in your case terminal may be representing tab
   as spaces, please check that first. You can use `cat -t filename` to
   see if you have any TAB in source file or not.  That command will
   display TAB character as ^I.

Comment: My `less` itself converts tab to spaces. This is not the case for `cat` though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not possible with less (see answer to the [same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412060/how-to-get-less-to-show-tabs-as-tabs) on unix.stackexchange).

As a workaround, it works with cat or, for some minimal paging capabilities, with the `more` command.